# ¿Herramientas para hacer pruebas de Stress en Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, webservice, aplicación-web, test

Qué tal. Estoy buscando herramientas de testeo que me sirvan para Angular JS.
JMeter no lo soporta. Anduve investigando otras herramientas, y la que más se acerca es Gatling, pero no tiene las métricas para saber en cuánto tiempo se cae el servidor.

¿Tienen alguna otra idea?

Answer (score 0):

Para los que deseen saber, utilicé Apache Jmeter.

Es la que más se acercó y funciona bastante bien en las pruebas de estrés.

¡Saludos!